# How can I transfer exception text from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.5

I have a file download mechanism with axios and laravel. From the side of php I have several situations where I have to throw exceptions.

for example

```
    $result = file_put_contents($filepath, $filedata);

    if($result){

        $photoModer = new PhotoModeration();
        $photoModer->newUserUpload($filepath);


        return true;
    }else{
        throw new Exceptions\FileUploadException('Can not upload file');
    }
```

In my controller I pass the data to the side js with json array

```
       if($resultUpload === true){

       $json_array = [
           'status' => 'success',
           'message' => 'Success'
       ];

   }else{

       $json_array = [
           'status' => 'error',
           'message' => 'Error'
       ];

   }

    return json_encode($json_array);
```

then in js I just use `result.text` . My question is in the following. 
Is it possible, in any way, to pass the text from exception to the side js?

Comment: Use try catch to get the error, and return your own format to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As  @J.Meijer mentioned, you can use `try ... catch` statement.
so your code will be:

```
try (file_put_contents($filepath, $filedata)){

    $photoModer = new PhotoModeration();
    $photoModer->newUserUpload($filepath);

    return true;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return json_encode($e);
}
```

I didn't test this code so that this only give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel this mechanism already exists

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#render-method